# Lots of GET value parameters on multiple actions - should they be unified under the same object?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, model-view-controller, attributes

I've got a few GET actions that end up requiring 8 to 10 parameters, all abbreviated with attributes. Should I consider moving them to an object, and passing them with a [FromQuery] attribute, while everything else be defined inside them, or not?

From a performance perspective, I don't think there's any overheard on me defining the attributes on the method's parameters directly, versus passing an object.

Comment: As long as the attributes are still valid, if they are defined on the properties. I do not see any problem with it.

Comment: @Twenty the only downside to merging them is the fact that I can't document them in swagger UI the same way a parameter would. (You can no longer use `<param name ="<your parameter here">`)

Comment: Do you know for a fact, that it isn't possible? That would seem pretty weird to me, since it is pretty common these days and this feature exists for quite a while now.

Comment: @Twenty It's impossible to document the parameters from inside a complex object, the way you can normal properties? Damn. I should open a github case on that one!

Comment: Well, I guess you answered yourself though. Go open up an GitHub issue and stay what you currently have until something changes?